# Interplay between the trace operator and the positive part of a Sobolev function

Tags: reference-request, sobolev-spaces, positivity

I consider the Sobolev trace $\gamma \colon H^1 (\mathbb{R}^{N+1}_{+}) \to H^{1/2}(\mathbb{R}^N)$. Let $U^{+}$ denote the positive part of a function $U$. It is correct, or only meaningful, to say that $\gamma(U^{+})=\gamma(U)^{+}$?
I can't find any result in the most popular textbooks I know of. Of course one *feels* that this should be true, but I can't prove it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

$H^1(R^{n+1}_+)$ embeds into $C(R^+,L^2(R^n))$, and you can apply $\gamma$ there. So it is correct. Of course this does not imply that $\gamma$ maps $H^{1/2}(R^n)$ to itself.

Comment: And this should be true because of the Sobolev embedding theorem in 1D, applied to the map $t \in \mathbb{R}_{+} \mapsto U(\cdot,t)$?